# fail2ban does not start jails on cenots 7

Tags: fail2ban, jail

SOLVED - sshd conf file was in wrong directory and with wrong extension

i have fallowed this tutorial [htf](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-fail2ban-on-centos/) and everything went smoothly, fail2ban starts nicely, i disabled selinux just in case, but sshd jail just does not start. I tried messing with config and when there is some mistake fail2ban does not start but when i remove stuff i changed then it starts but there are no jails.

so fallowing the tutorial i made file `/etc/fail2ban/sshd.local`

```
[sshd]
enabled = true
port = ssh
action = firewallcmd-ipset
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
maxretry = 5
bantime = 86400
```

i also tried to put path to logfile( `logpath = /var/log/secure`) instead of `logpath = %(sshd_log)s` but there is still no sshd jail:

```
Status
|- Number of jail:  0
`- Jail list:
```

i changed logging level to DEBUG in `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf`

```
[DEFAULT]

# Option: loglevel
# Notes.: Set the log level output.
#         CRITICAL
#         ERROR
#         WARNING
#         NOTICE
#         INFO
#         DEBUG
# Values: [ LEVEL ]  Default: ERROR
#
loglevel = DEBUG
```

with a bit more loggin inside of `/var/log/fail2ban.log` but i only get a tiny bit more logging which is irrelevant to jails.

```
2021-07-14 19:14:49,952 fail2ban.server         [19586]: INFO    Starting Fail2ban v0.11.1
2021-07-14 19:14:49,953 fail2ban.server         [19586]: DEBUG   Creating PID file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
2021-07-14 19:14:49,953 fail2ban.observer       [19586]: INFO    Observer start...
2021-07-14 19:14:49,954 fail2ban.server         [19586]: DEBUG   Starting communication
2021-07-14 19:14:49,961 fail2ban.database       [19586]: INFO    Connected to fail2ban persistent database '/var/lib/fail2ban/fail2ban.sqlite3'
2021-07-14 19:14:49,964 fail2ban.transmitter    [19586]: DEBUG   Status: ready
```

I also made changes in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` where i replaced:

```
backend = auto
```

to

```
backend = polling
```

i was wondering if anyone know what tools are on my disposal to debug not working jails?

Comment: how should `sshd.local` be fetched by any config file? i only know about `jail.local`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed your jail configuration file in the wrong directory.

To wit:

```
/etc/fail2ban/sshd.local
```

Fail2ban will never read this file because it is misplaced.

Jail definitions should be placed in the `/etc/fail2ban/jail.d` directory with a name ending in `.conf`. A quick and dirty one off can also be placed in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` but this is less maintainable.

Comment: wow you are right, i read the tutorial million times to check if i did everything correctly and somehow i keep making the same mistake. Thank you

Comment: @Belutak Remember to mark it as solved by clicking the tick mark so that it turns solid green.

Comment: i thought its in my post and took me a wile to find it :D